# Learning python, I'm trying to make a fahrenheit conversion using a defined function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
celsius = input("Please enter degrees in celcius: ")
fahrenheit = 0

def f_conversion(celsius):
    ((celsius * 1.8) + 32 == fahrenheit)



print("Your temp in fahrenheit is: " + str(fahrenheit))
```

Any clues on to why this isnt working out?

Comment: What exactly isn't working??

Comment: No matter what, I only return 0

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you spend more time following a basic Python tutorial, there would be much to much to cover here - and SO isn't meant to replace tutorials.

Comment: (1) You never run the function (2) The function doesn't return anything (3) Why are you checking if it is equal to Fahrenheit in the function?

Comment: Welcome to python and StackOverflow, and python.  The question included code that did not result in the desired result. Well done that is what is known as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Remember input always returns a string
celsius = input("Please enter degrees in celcius: ")
# celsius identifies a location im memory which contains a string
celsius = float(celsius)
# Now the name celsius locates memory of type float
# fahrenheit = 0 # A global value not needed here.
# fahrenheit identifies a location im memory which contains an integer = 0

def f_conversion(celsius):
    fahrenheit = (celsius * 1.8) + 32  # Computes the conversion
    return fahrenheit


print("Your temp in fahrenheit is: " + str(f_conversion(celsius)))
```

Comment: Thank you !!! i really appreciate the insight, help, and your time!

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no need to initialize variables in python. So setting fahrenheit to zero right away is unnecessary.

Second, in the function itself, you are making an equality call. `==` checks for equality while `=` sets variable values. Moreover, you are doing so backwards, fahrenheit would be on the left and assigned with `=` the result of the conversion.

Your script might instead look something like this:

```
celsius = float(input("Please enter degrees in celcius: "))

def conversion(celsius):
    return ((celsius * 9/5) +32)

result = conversion(celsius)

print (f"Your temp in fahrenheit is {result}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```py
celsius = int(input("Please enter degrees in celcius: "))
fahrenheit = (celsius * 1.8) + 32
print("Your temp in fahrenheit is: " + str(fahrenheit))
```

A couple of pointers here:

1. using the input() function returns the user input as a string and not an integer, so you have to use int(input()) to bind the variable celsius to the input as an integer.

EDIT: The integer data type is for whole numbers. If you want to use fractional values for celcius, use float(input()) instead.

2. you do not need to write the conversion as a function. It is just a numeric callculation that Python can evaluate as an expression.
3. in your code, you never actually call the function you wrote, you only defined it.

Hope this helps, and I would echo Thierry Lathuille's suggestion of working through a basic course. It won't take too long and it will get you off to al flying start.